# how can I convert entities(list) to dictionary? my tried code is commented and not working, NLP problem

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

how can I convert entities(list) to dictionary? my tried code is commented and not working, or instead of converting how can I rewrite entities to be like a dictionary?
I want to convert in dictionary to be able to find 5 most frequently named people in the first 500 sentence.

```
! pip install wget
import wget
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirkhovy/NLPclass/master/data/moby_dick.txt'
wget.download(url, 'moby_dick.txt')
documents = [line.strip() for line in open('moby_dick.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()]

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
entities = [[(entity.text, entity.label_) for entity in nlp(sentence).ents]for sentence in documents[:50]]
entities


#I TRIED THIS BUT IS WRONG
#def Convert(lst): 
#    res_dct = {lst[i]: lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)} 
#    return res_dct
#print(Convert(ent))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list stored in variable `entities` is has type `list[list[tuple[str, str]]]`, where the first entry in the tuple is the string for the entity and the second is the type of the entity, e.g.:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(entities)
[[],
 [('Ishmael', 'GPE')],
 [('Some years ago', 'DATE')],
 [],
 [('November', 'DATE')],
 [],
 [('Cato', 'ORG')],
 [],
 [],
 [('Manhattoes', 'ORG'), ('Indian', 'NORP')],
 [],
 [('a few hours', 'TIME')],
...
```

Then you can create a reverse `dict` in the following way:

```
>>> sum(filter(None, entities), [])
[('Ishmael', 'GPE'), ('Some years ago', 'DATE'), ('November', 'DATE'), ('Cato', 'ORG'), ('Manhattoes', 'ORG'), ('Indian', 'NORP'), ('a few hours', 'TIME'), ('Sabbath afternoon', 'TIME'), ('Corlears Hook to Coenties Slip', 'WORK_OF_ART'), ('Whitehall', 'PERSON'), ('thousands upon thousands', 'CARDINAL'), ('China', 'GPE'), ('week days', 'DATE'), ('ten', 'CARDINAL'), ('American', 'NORP'), ('June', 'DATE'), ('one', 'CARDINAL'), ('Niagara', 'ORG'), ('thousand miles', 'QUANTITY'), ('Tennessee', 'GPE'), ('two', 'CARDINAL'), ('Rockaway Beach', 'GPE'), ('first', 'ORDINAL'), ('first', 'ORDINAL'), ('Persians', 'NORP')]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> type2entities = defaultdict(list)
>>> for entity, entity_type in sum(filter(None, entities), []):
...   type2entities[entity_type].append(entity)
...
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(type2entities)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'CARDINAL': ['thousands upon thousands', 'ten', 'one', 'two'],
             'DATE': ['Some years ago', 'November', 'week days', 'June'],
             'GPE': ['Ishmael', 'China', 'Tennessee', 'Rockaway Beach'],
             'NORP': ['Indian', 'American', 'Persians'],
             'ORDINAL': ['first', 'first'],
             'ORG': ['Cato', 'Manhattoes', 'Niagara'],
             'PERSON': ['Whitehall'],
             'QUANTITY': ['thousand miles'],
             'TIME': ['a few hours', 'Sabbath afternoon'],
             'WORK_OF_ART': ['Corlears Hook to Coenties Slip']})
```

The `dict` stored in variable `type2entities` is what you want. To get the most frequent people's names in the first 500 lines (and their corresponding number of mentions):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> entities = [[(entity.text, entity.label_) for entity in nlp(sentence).ents]for sentence in documents[:500]]
>>> person_cnt = Counter()
>>> for entity, entity_type in sum(filter(None, entities), []):
...   if entity_type == 'PERSON':
...     person_cnt[entity] += 1
...
>>> person_cnt.most_common(5)
[('Queequeg', 17), ('don', 4), ('Nantucket', 2), ('Jonah', 2), ('Sal', 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks alot, do you know from this reverse dictionary how can I  find 5 most frequently named people in the first 500 sentence. I was thinking smth like this                                  ``` track={}

for key,value in ent.items():
    if value not in track:
        track[value]=0
    else:
        track[value]+=1

print(max(track,key=track.get))
```

Comment: @elham I've updated the answer to do that. If you think that's helpful can you upvote the answer and accept? Thanks!